# Magento create new user role white/blank page

Tags: admin, admin-panel, user-roles, user

When I want to add a new user role I get a white/blank page. Every other page in the admin seems to work fine except this page.

Does somebody have a sollution or a way to check what is wrong?

Comment: In order to check what is wrong, always [have a look at the log files](https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/666-analysing-logfiles-with-magento) first. In case they do not already provide the answer, update your question to include the respective log entry / stack trace.

Comment: I'd ask if you have any module installed for admin rights as well.